# Can't position the second background image

Tags: css, background, background-position

[image: Trouble positioning second background image]

```
body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #666464;
font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
font-size: 12px;
line-height: 1.4em; 

background-image: url( ../images/862a8380ba6984de1235023a8eef20e7.png), url(../images/green-heart-tree-PNG-thumb20.png);
background-position: top bottom, right top; 
background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
```

}

For some reason, I am not able to position the green heart at all, why? I don't get it. Thanks for your help guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified the position for your first picture to be `top` and `bottom`, that messes it up.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #666464;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.4em; 

    background-image: url( ../images/862a8380ba6984de1235023a8eef20e7.png), url(../images/green-heart-tree-PNG-thumb20.png);
    background-position: top left, right top; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}
```